# typescript inference without enumerating all possibilities

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I would like to know if there is a solution for the following problem :
I have two functions that accept different input parameters, I have an object mapping each function to a string.

I define a type that is a union type of object containing the key of one function in the map and a value matching the function parameters type.
Given an object with that type, I would like to retrieve the corresponding function from the map object and call it with the value but typescript does not do the type inference.

```js
const f1 = (value: number) => value;
const f2 = (value: string) => value;

const map = {
    f1,
    f2
};

type MyType = {
    fun: "f1";
    value: Parameters<typeof map["f1"]>;
} | {
    fun: "f2";
    value: Parameters<typeof map["f2"]>;
};

// does not work
const test1 = (b: MyType) => {
    map[b.fun].apply(null, b.value);
};

// works
const test2 = (b: MyType) => {
    if (b.fun === "f1") {
        map[b.fun].apply(null, b.value);
    } else {
        map[b.fun].apply(null, b.value);
    }
};
```

Is it possible to do something like this without having to enumerate all possibilities in a switch or if/else ?

Answer (score 3):

You've run into TypeScript's less-than-stellar support for what I've been calling [correlated record types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Right now it sees that `b.fun` is a union type `"f1" | "f2"`,  and that `b.value` is a union type `[string] | [number]`, and it treats these as *uncorrelated*.  Normally [a union of functions can only be called with an *intersection* of its parameters](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types), which in this case would be `[string] & [number]`.  Since `[string] | [number]` is not assignable to `[string] & [number]`, the compiler complains.  In fact no value is assignable to `[string] & [number]`, since its first element would need to be a `string & number` which is equivalent to `never`.

In order for the compiler to verify that `map[b.fun].apply(null, b.value)` is type safe, it would essentially need to analyze the code multiple times, one for each possible type of `b`.  You can make this happen explicitly by duplicating the code in a `switch`/`case` or `if`/`else` statement, but it doesn't happen automatically (which makes sense because it would lead to exponentially increasing compile times as the number of union-typed values in code increases), and [you can't even ask the compiler to do it on an opt-in basis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051).

For now, the only reasonable workaround is to accept that you know more than the compiler about the type safety of the code, and to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or the equivalent to tell the compiler not to worry about it, like this:

```
type MapVals = typeof map[keyof typeof map];
type LooselyTypedMapFunction = (...x: Parameters<MapVals>) => ReturnType<MapVals>
const test1 = (b: MyType) => {
  (map[b.fun] as LooselyTypedMapFunction).apply(null, b.value);
};
```

Here the type `LooseLyTypedMapFunction` ends up taking the types of `f1` and `f2` and blurring them into a single function that accepts and produces `string | number`.  And we use the type assertion `map[b.fun] as LooselyTypedMapFunction` to lie a little bit to the compiler.  We're telling it that `map[b.fun]` will accept a `string` and it will also accept a `number`.  This is false, of course, but will not run into a problem as long as you pass in the correlated `b.value` list and not some random thing like `[Math.random()<0.5 ? "oops" : 123]).

That type assertion might be more work than you want to do, but at least it might catch if you passed anything too crazy into `map[b.fun]`, since `[string] | [number]` will at least prohibit `[{foo: string}]`.  You can use a less safe assertion like this:

```
const test2 = (b: MyType) => {
  (map[b.fun] as Function).apply(null, b.value);
};
```

which doesn't require type juggling of a `LooselyTypedMapFunction` but will also accept `(map[b.fun] as Function).apply(null, [{foo: 123}]);`.  So be careful.

---

Okay, hope that gives you some direction.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgRhgXhgCgG4EMA2BXAUwC4Yw8BbAIwICcBKFAPhm3wIG4AoUSWOAJhTpWhEtBoBLMAHMGyZiI6du4aDHJYADkIDenGPAQAaffH6cAvl05QAnpoIwAsrYAq9x6j0G4eMCQAiRACuA0USAAUsGixyAihaCAAeOwcQOHUtAG0ghACAXUYuCxgAHxhveD9AgRDTcJgomLiEmmTUgnTMzRzawuLrDuctADVcCCEOro0egGsCWy6pjJn8riGAGRAQCAIcNw8AEyctADE-YCgJcCE0ADoHgA9I6Nj4xKSTzTGcCEY5ZgAJXieBoYHcDk+o3GjBUvBgCWgSFQaEoJBcEIIAIqpjQMyylDuvjA+RgWAmWx2ewODmOZwuV3AdDuWk0+zQZBwOCMMEJijoA2UPDUiKgghRaOcNKxTBxBjx2UJxNJ5Jg5zAl2uYGZrPZnO5vLu-NC6HxSr8Kom6s1TJZmjZtg5eC5PKyOjg2xICH4AGYLPkBZZQkA)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already use the type assertion trick but I was wondering if three was another solution. I will follow the github issue you shared.

Answer (score 1):

With support for [correlated union types #30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) finally landed in TS, you could write:

```ts
type TypeMap = {
    f1: number;
    f2: string;
}

const f1 = (value: number) => value;
const f2 = (value: string) => value;

const map: { [K in keyof TypeMap]: (value: TypeMap[K]) => TypeMap[K] } = {
    f1,
    f2
};

type MyType<K extends keyof TypeMap> = { [P in K]: { fun: P, value: TypeMap[P] } }[K];

const test1 = <K extends keyof TypeMap>(b: MyType<K>) => {
    return map[b.fun](b.value);
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.0-dev.20211216&ssl=18&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEFkCGYoF4oG8BQU9QDMBGALigDsBXAWwCMIAnAbl3wICYyBnYBgS3IBzFgF9s2AMYB7cj0JF0UABQA3JABtKEMlTqMAlOgB8UNZogtps4IXaLVGrd14DBhtCbNaWkmXOooZJhQANoA0lACUADWECBSBLDwyGAAumQO5mRwkCnhqe4mOYgo%20VAiijj48gA0rHgc2CI%20oJBQCCDFADwREAAewBDkACZcMXEJSbkoJhjBIQAKkeRQYelYhJTkZAs1po7aUyVgi6nl5fk%20VnKDPAoYPVD9gyNjsfGJxSlGSrRkHd0wkZClh6lAGBBgJQGCsAidaAA6AhbVK-BFeCD6URXPxSdQQBHqKSCJS3YBEJRVNhbMgAcmItLq1QxZHYTX0%20nE1zxBKJJLJFKpDRpUHp7EZYJZUAAREhaBJpezOUA)