# Can the cast to any be avoided with better type definitions?

Tags: typescript

My question is best described with the help of the following snippet. I have included comments within the code which hopefully defines the question clearly.

```js
type MediaKinds = "video" | "audio";

type IMediaData<TType extends MediaKinds, TValue> = {
  type: TType,
  value: TValue
}

type VideoMedia = IMediaData<"video", { videoData: string }>;
type AudioMedia = IMediaData<"audio", { audioData: string }>;

type MediaTypes = VideoMedia | AudioMedia

function playVideo(media: VideoMedia) {
  console.log("playing " + media.value.videoData);
}

function playAudio(media: AudioMedia) {
  console.log("playing " + media.value.audioData);
}

type PickMediaByKey<T, K extends MediaKinds> = T extends { type: K } ? T : never;

type MediaPlayers = {
  [key in MediaKinds]: (media: PickMediaByKey<MediaTypes, key>) => void
}

/*
  Here, the MediaPlayers type forces the properties to be assigned the correct functions.
  For example { video: playAudio, audio: playVideo } will be an error.
*/
const players: MediaPlayers = {
  video: playVideo,
  audio: playAudio
}

function playMedia(media: MediaTypes) {  
  /*
    Here lies my question: Is there a way to avoid 'casting' media as 'any'?

    This casting should not be necessary.
    If media.type === 'video', then players[media.type] is guaranteed to be a function which takes VideoMedia. 
  */
  players[media.type](media as any)
}

playMedia({
  type: "video",
  value: { videoData: "a video stream" }
})
```

So the question is: Is there a way to avoid `media as any` within the playMedia function, given that the code is compile-time verifiable without it?

Comment: Looks like you want what I've been calling [correlated record types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  There's not really any great support for this.  You can possibly change it so that your assertion isn't quite as unsafe as `any` but it'll still need something like an assertion to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't think there's anything great here for you.  In the [question this duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082214/typescript-inference-without-enumerating-all-possibilities) I write out the current not-so-great options.  For your code this would look like either duplication:

```
if (media.type === "audio") {
  players[media.type](media);
} else {
  players[media.type](media);
}
```

or assertion to an appropriate union-or-intersection in the right place:

```
players[media.type](media as
  IMediaData<"video", { videoData: string; }> & IMediaData<"audio", { audioData: string; }>
);
```

or giving up entirely with `any`:

```
players[media.type](media as any);
```

Your `any` assertion is probably the way I'd recommend; just document that you know better than the compiler, and if the definition of `media` ever changes you should come back and triple-check the types.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll go with ```any`` for now - since I have the equivalent of thirty media types. Sorry about missing the duplicate - since I was not sure of the terminology involved I couldn't come up with effective search queries. 'Correlated record types' is a good one.